# writeJSONString don't fill my file

Tags: json, scala

this simple piece of code create an empty file despite I try to write the json into a file.

```
import java.io.{File, FileWriter, IOException}

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request
import org.json.simple.JSONArray
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
/**
  *  * Created by Administrator on 02/01/2018.
  */
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val res = "[{\"price\":\"100\",\"bookName\":\"Java\"}]"
      val jsonParser = new JSONParser
      val json = jsonParser.parse(res).asInstanceOf[JSONArray]
      val file = new File("myjson_" + System.currentTimeMillis / 1000 + ".json")
      val writer = new FileWriter(file)
      json.writeJSONString(writer)
      println(json)
    }
}
```

When I run It, as I said below, the json is empty. I have tried to replace my jsonArray containing 1 jsonObject to a JsonArray containing 500JsonObject. I get only 482 records and the last one is truncated. Do you have any idea or do you obtain the same result??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not forget to close `FileWriter` to flush the stream.

```
writer.close()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for the answer. You are right but It does not change the result. Do you get an empty file too?

Comment: Hi, Thank for your comment. I edit the question to add import lines

Comment: It works fine. The issue you described is caused by the missing call to `close`.

Comment: In fact forget my previous comment, It work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: ```toJSONString()``` method was also truncating last few results in my project, and this answer solved the problem.